# Unsure of how to make this calculator function work

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/DamascusCode/project/full/AyvgYD/)

For a math project due very soon.

I've tried to apply the DRY concept, but I don't know how. I started to write a function that would apply for all of the numbers, but halfway through it I realized there's no way it would work. The anonymous functions need to be changed I know that, yet I can't right now as I don't know another way to implement it.

```
document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function) {
  num = document.getElementById('something'); 

  if (num != null && num === document.getElementById("zero")) {
    calculation = calculation.concat("0");
  } else if (num != null && num === document.getElementById("one")) {
    calculation = calculation.concat("1");
  } else if (num != null === && num document.getElementbyId("two")) {
    calculation = calculation.concat("2");
  } else if (num != nul && num === document.getElementbyId("three")) {
    calculation = calculation.concat("3");
  } else if (num != nul && num === document.getElementbyId("four")) {
    calculation = calculation.concat("4");
  } else if (num != nul && num === document.getElementbyId("five")) {
    calculation = calculation.concat("5");
  } else if (num != nul && num === document.getElementbyId()) {
    calculation = calculation.concat("6");
  }
}
```

Each number is inside a button which is inside a table. They also have id's identifying which number they are. I'm not looking for code, don't want to plagiarize anything. Just looking for suggestions on what I could do differently.

Comment: `num === document.getElementById("zero")` is comparing one object to another object. They’re different objects, so this will always be `false`. You need to compare their values. And at some point you started writing `nul` instead of `null`. Your second `else if` has incorrect syntax.

Comment: General points: `document.querySelector(".button")` selects the *first* element with a *class* of `"button"`. If you want to select a `<button>` element remove the `"."` from the selector. If you want to select *all* buttons, you'd need `.querySelectorAll("button")`, and then you'd need to loop over the resulting list to attach an event listener to the individual items (you can't attach an event listener to an element list). To concatenate a value to the end of a string you can just say `calculation += "0"`, no need for the `.concat()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest method will be writing a common function:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener(
    "click",
    function() {
    var current_value = this.innerHTML; //typed single number
    var display_value = document.getElementById('display').value; //the value on the calculator display
    var new_value = display_value + '' + current_value; //+''+ to make it string
    document.getElementById('display').value = new_value;
  });
}
```

Try this and add exceptions and calculation functions with same method as above by filtering '+','-', etc. values.

Comment: Note that this event handler is bound only to the *first* button.

Comment: @nnnnnn :Thanks. Edited the answer.

Comment: But...your edit has nothing to do with what I said. Also, note that both `current_value` and `display_value` will already be strings.

Answer (score 0):

i think its easier if you use jquery..just a suggestion.

please see the fiddle.

i have added a class 'show' to all buttons which we want to display on the screen on click and class 'calc' for all operator buttons..replaced your display javascript with the following jquery

```
var calculation='';
$('button.show').click(function(){
 calculation = calculation.concat($(this).text());
 $('#screen').text(calculation);
});
```

And also added scripts for the calculation

Please see the fiddle [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7d1hmea/50/)